# Add MS Word bookmark via pandoc

Tags: ms-word, pandoc

Markdown files processed via pandoc can certainly have cross-references, called links, such as

```
[text](#link)
```

How do I add a Microsoft Word "bookmark"? Is there a special "plug-in" or "filter" to do that? Such as

pseudo-code

```
[text](#this_is_a_ms_word_bookmark)
```